# Error Building NGINX with HTTP/3 Support on Windows: NMAKE Fatal Error U1077 with OpenSSL 3.0.13

Tags: nginx, openssl, http3

I am a total beginner in NGINX and wanted to use HTTP/3 but the docs say that it is not an inbuilt module and for config nginx code has to be built.
I followed this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-cj-p4rZtU step by step though it is an old video but the only one I found for building nginx on windows
I downloaded the following

1. NGINX 1.25.4
2. openssl-3.0.13
   and the following command to make the Makefile

```
./auto/configure                        \
        --with-cc=cl                        \
        --builddir=objs             \
        --with-debug                        \
        --prefix=                       \
        --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf             \
        --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid               \
        --http-log-path=logs/access.log             \
        --error-log-path=logs/error.log             \
        --sbin-path=nginx.exe                   \
        --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp  \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp          \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp      \
        --http-scgi-temp-path=temp/scgi_temp            \
        --http-uwsgi-temp-path=temp/uwsgi_temp          \
        --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024             \
        --with-pcre=objs/lib/pcre-8.44              \
        --with-zlib=objs/lib/zlib-1.3.1             \
        --with-http_v2_module                   \
        --with-http_v3_module                   \
        --with-http_realip_module               \
        --with-http_addition_module             \
        --with-http_sub_module                  \
        --with-http_dav_module                  \
        --with-http_stub_status_module              \
        --with-http_flv_module                  \
        --with-http_mp4_module                  \
        --with-http_gunzip_module               \
        --with-http_gzip_static_module              \
        --with-http_auth_request_module             \
        --with-http_random_index_module             \
        --with-http_secure_link_module              \
        --with-http_slice_module                \
        --with-mail                     \
        --with-stream                       \
        --with-stream_realip_module             \
        --with-stream_ssl_preread_module            \
        --with-openssl=objs/lib/openssl-3.0.13          \
        --with-openssl-opt="no-asm no-tests -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501" \
        --with-http_ssl_module                  \
        --with-mail_ssl_module                  \
        --with-stream_ssl_module
```

after using this command on vs tools cmd

```
nmake /f objs\MakeFile
```

I got this error
[image: error]
So what am I doing wrong? Can someone correct my mistake